# How can I avoid this indices error in my pandas apply statement?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm really lost on this error message, particularly as it seems to only occur in my 64 bit version of pandas, and not a slightly older 32 bit version I have in a different environment.

So I have two dataframes- "summary" and "all". "Summary" includes start times of types of events, whilst "all" contains data that's being interpreted into the summary table.

This line below that takes a 'starting reading' seems to be causing all the issues, not sure why though!

```
summary['average_after_start'] = summary.apply(lambda row: np.mean(all[(all['Timestamp'] >= row['Start'])]['Value']), axis=1, raw=True)
```

The error message I get is this:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

*edit: I've simplified this a bit to be the simplest code I can find so far that causes the issue

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: woops! Will edit the question to include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `raw=True` then `row` is a numpy array, not a pandas series and hence `row['Start']` will throw an error as you can't index an array with a string.
So you should change it to `raw=False` (which is the default, so you can leave it out).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This completely fixed my error, can't believe I spent so long debugging without noticing this.